# Symfony 2: How to build a really simple form, with just one field and use it in controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, webforms, symfony-forms

I'm building a get started procedure. It is really very simple: just one field for the email and a submit button.

**HOW DOES THE PROCEDURE WORKS**
I simply have one controller with two methods: `indexAction()` and `endAction()`
The indexAction simply set the route using annotations and displays the twig template with an handmade form:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class GetStartedController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("getstarted")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array(
            // ...
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("getstarted/end", name="getStartedEnd")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function endAction(Request $request)
    {

    // ... other code
```

As you can see, currently the method really does nothing as the form is handmade directly in the twig template.

Here is the code to render the form (handmade in the twig template):

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}AppBundle:GetStarted:index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form id="getStarted" action="{{ path('getStartedEnd') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your e-mail (es.: your.name@example.com">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

*I know Symfony 2 can handle the [creation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form) of the form and [its rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form) on the page, but this is a very simple form and I know it never will be more complicate, so an handmade one is the simplest and fastest solution.*

**Now, what's the problem? The problem is I don't understand how to get the form and its submitted values in my controller, in the other method, `endAction()`.**

The form has as action the path to the other method, `endAction()` where, in my intentions, I will retrieve the submitted values and do some stuff with them.

Following the instructions in paragraph [Using a Form without a Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class), i came up with the following code for the method `endAction()` that, in my intentions, will retrieve the submitted email and do something with it - will create a user, obviously - (note the `exit` to simply print the results of the `if`)

```
/**
 * @Route("getstarted/end", name="getStartedEnd")
 * @Template()
 */
public function endAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('userEmail', 'email')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        print_r($data);
    } else {
        echo 'no data submitted';
    }

    exit;


    return array(
            // ...
        );
}
```

The problem is that `if ($form->isValid()) {` ever returns false and I ever obtain as result the printing of `echo 'no data submitted';`

Clearly there is something wrong with my implementation of the form handling, but... What?

**This is my question: what am I doing wrong? Why the form isn't "intercepted" in the controller?**

Comment: how does Symphony know if your form is valid if you didn't create any validation rules for it? Are there any?

Comment: I think, because your hand made form is missing the csrf_token. But you can omit it, by setting the csrf_protection option to false in your end Action.

Comment: No, there aren't validation rules but also with a simple print_r($form->getData()) nothing is printed.

Comment: If the problem was the csrf protection i should see some kind of error, but no one is displayed (obviously, without the exit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two things to do:

First, edit your Form template and use the correct names (name="form[userEmail]" instead of name="userEmail"):

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{{ path('getStartedEnd') }}">
    <div id="form">
        <div>
            <label for="form_userEmail" class="required">User email</label>
            <input type="email" id="form_userEmail" name="form[userEmail]" required="required"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And second disable the csrf protection of the form:

```
/**
 * @Route("getstarted/end", name="getStartedEnd")
 * @Template()
 */
public function endAction(Request $request)
{
   $data = array();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data, array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ))
    ->add('userEmail', 'email')
    ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        print_r($data);
    } else {
        echo 'no data submitted';
    }

    exit;


    return array(
        // ...
    );

 }
```

But recommend strongly not to render the form by hand!

It's not more than:

```
/**
 * @Route("getstarted")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $data = array();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('getStartedEnd'),
    ))
    ->add('userEmail', 'email')
    ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

and in your template:

```
{# just this line #}
{{ form(form) }}
```

Comment: Yes, i jumped some steps: never jump steps! Thank you to have put me again on the right way!

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Particularly, how to add the action parameter to `createFormBuilder($args)` because it's very unclear in the Symfony docs. They inject a model as the arg and it's confusing to me since the model has no constructer or action parameters